# How to return feature.shape from server by using WCF and ArcGIS Silverlight API?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, wcf

I am using the ArcGIS Silverlight API. I all I need to do is to get the geometry from a feature by objectid to zoom to it:

```
getFeature(objectid);
```

So I used WCF service to get the geometry but I received the following error:

```
Type 'System.__ComObject' cannot be serialized
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually I found a solution

using Query Task and pass in the where clause the filter like

query.where="objectid=17";

but when i need to save edit delete in sde use WCF service

that's set

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to send a request to a server with a url [compliant with Esri's REST API](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/SDK/REST/index.html?feature.html).

For example, to retrieve a the feature whose ObjectID=2, passing this url:

```
http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/0/2?f=pjson
```

The server returns a response that includes attributes and geometry:

```
{
  "feature" : 
  {
    "attributes" : {
      "FID" : 2, 
      "CITY_FIPS" : "01990", 
      "CITY_NAME" : "Anacortes", 
      "STATE_FIPS" : "53", 
      "STATE_NAME" : "Washington", 
      "STATE_CITY" : "5301990", 
      "TYPE" : "city", 
      "CAPITAL" : "N", 
      "ELEVATION" : -99, 
      "POP1990" : 11451, 
      "HOUSEHOLDS" : 4669, 
      "MALES" : 5506, 
      "FEMALES" : 5945, 
      "WHITE" : 10945, 
      "BLACK" : 62, 
      "AMERI_ES" : 192, 
      "ASIAN_PI" : 154, 
      "OTHER" : 98, 
      "HISPANIC" : 233, 
      "AGE_UNDER5" : 725, 
      "AGE_5_17" : 1981, 
      "AGE_18_64" : 6276, 
      "AGE_65_UP" : 2469, 
      "NEVERMARRY" : 1420, 
      "MARRIED" : 5818, 
      "SEPARATED" : 151, 
      "WIDOWED" : 833, 
      "DIVORCED" : 916, 
      "HSEHLD_1_M" : 437, 
      "HSEHLD_1_F" : 711, 
      "MARHH_CHD" : 1032, 
      "MARHH_NO_C" : 1777, 
      "MHH_CHILD" : 76, 
      "FHH_CHILD" : 255, 
      "HSE_UNITS" : 4992, 
      "VACANT" : 323, 
      "OWNER_OCC" : 3181, 
      "RENTER_OCC" : 1488, 
      "MEDIAN_VAL" : 85300, 
      "MEDIANRENT" : 342, 
      "UNITS_1DET" : 3724, 
      "UNITS_1ATT" : 121, 
      "UNITS2" : 134, 
      "UNITS3_9" : 380, 
      "UNITS10_49" : 353, 
      "UNITS50_UP" : 0, 
      "MOBILEHOME" : 200
    }
    , 
    "geometry" : 
    {
      "x" : -122.630685404, 
      "y" : 48.492215849
    }
  }
}
```

ArcObjects cannot be used within a silverlight app.  If you want to turn a resulting REST geometry into an ArcObjects IGeometry, I would use Esri's WPF library to parse the REST, then convert the WPF geometry into an IGeometry.

Comment: thank you for your reply it's so helpful, kindly if you can give me more details on how to use this url in silverlight application to return the results